# How to run a website in Azure using same URL?

Tags: azure

Our company has two sites

www.mysite.com         -- Wordpress site
www.mysite.com/portal  -- asp.net mvc site

We want to move the wordpress site (www.mysite.com) to Azure and the other site stays local.  We need to url stay the same. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you state that you need the URL to stay the same, this can be achieved through a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). You would set up a web server (typically nginx or IIS) answering on www.mysite.com.

This web server would have reverse proxy rules to forward requests for `/portal` to your on-premises server (in a given, non-public IP and port) and all other requests to another web server running WordPress (on the same server/cluster that runs the reverse proxy, or a separate one), also with a given IP and port.

All user requests, then, would reach the reverse proxy, that would serve them from cache if possible, or forward them to the internal web servers, and send the response back to the user, transparently. Notice that this is an internal operation, not a redirect response.

Although this setup is more complex than the simpler solution of using different subdomains (www.mysite.com for website and portal.mysite.com for application), it comes with certain advantages that are described in the referenced [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), such as security and acceleration.

Alternatively you could create separate subdomains as described above, and use a redirect rule to redirect requests for `www.mysite.com/portal/x` to `portal.mysite.com/x`. In this case, the user would see the updated URL in their browser, but the old ones would still work.